# How can I tell a Svelte component's property has been changed by the parent?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm using Svelte to build some forms that are tied to web sockets.  If the user changes a value, the component will send a PUT request to update the data, then the server will broadcast the change to all users.  But that puts me in a weird predicament.

The main page looks like this:

```
<script>
  import { UOM } from './channels';  // <-- A readable store of an array of objects.
  import UOMEdit from './UOMEdit.svelte';
</script>

{#each $UOM as unit (unit.uomId)}
  <UOMEdit uom="{unit}"/>
{/each}
```

And UOMEdit is basically this:

```
<script>
  export let uom;
  let { uomId, name, standardUnitId, toStdUnitMultiplyer } = uom;
</script>

<!-- Various controls to manipulate the UOM's data -->
```

This works fine for this user, but if the value of "uom" changes it's not reflected in the control.  In other words, other users won't see any changes this user makes.  So then I tried this kind of arrangement:

```
<script>
  export let uom;
  $: uomId = uom.uomId;
  $: name = uom.name;
  $: standardUnitId = uom.standardUnitId;
  $: toStdUnitMultiplyer = uom.toStdUnitMultiplyer;
</script>
```

And now I've got the opposite problem.  I can see any changes broadcast by the server but can't make any changes locally.

I prefer the idea of destructuring the property into variables because it keeps everything so simple.  Is there some way to know that the difference between the uom's properties and the local variables is because the uom has changed and not because the user has been tinkering with the local copy?

Comment: You could create a copy of `uom` in `onMount()` and then, in `afterUpdate()`, compare the new `uom` to the copy. If it differs, you know the update has come from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That seems to be where I'm headed.  Recently I wasted a lot of time working with transitions only to find out Svelte had already solved my problem for me but that may not be the case here.  I'll update my original question.

Comment: How are going to solve race condition? E.g. if two users change the values simultaneously what should be shown it the form?

Comment: That's a good question, and it has caused me a little concern.  For my use, changes are made via PUT request and reflected by web sockets.  So at the moment on the client's side, I'm saying web sockets always win.  If you change a value and an update comes from the server with a matching value, discard the local user's changes (since they match).  If you're in the middle of changing a value and an update arrives, update the form right out from under the user but tell them why.  That wasn't my first choice but it was the best idea I could come up with.

Comment: One other thing I should add.  The client socket uses a little RxJs to debounce messages from the server for about half a second.  That definitely has helped cut down on senseless chatter and intermittent changes causing various pages to recalculate for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I'm not overlooking any built in solution for this.  As @Christian has suggested I decided to just make an extra copy to use for comparison when something changes.  This is essentially the new version of UOMEdit:

```
<script>
  export let uom;

  let localCopy = Object.assign({}, uom);
  let { uomId, name, standardUnitId, toStdUnitMultiplyer } = localCopy;

  $: if (JSON.stringify(uom) !== JSON.stringify(localCopy)) {
    // The original was changed outside this component.
  }
</script>
```